# how to add 'Email' connection type to apache airflow

Tags: email, smtp, connection, airflow

I am not able to see the 'Email' connection type and trying to add one to the airflow server. Can you point me how to add the 'Email' connection type? I am setting up smtp to send email from my dag.

Comment: Hi Vishal, which is the Airflow version you are using?

Answer (score 0):

You can set any connection - for example HTTP and name it properly. The specicic Email connection type will be added in Airflow 2.3.0 but only login/password are used from the connection so you can use any other connection type.